# ADT field not being set

Tags: java, android

I'm running a simple java project on Android (using Eclipse ADT).
During debugging I see that a value is not set correctly.
I think this screenshot says it all:

[image: debug screen shot]

Any idea what can cause this?

Thanks a lot,
Omer

Comment: it is final so it can not be changed even if I wanted to

Comment: Where exactly is the breakpoint ? This might be related to the process of instantiation of classes in Java.

Comment: The breakpoint is in the IS_IN_PRODUCTION_ENVIRUNMENT init, the value remains false the entire progam's life. That is why I started debugging in the first place.

Comment: 1. is it happening all the time.. 2. what is the next line of the variable? is it a method?

Comment: @StinePike , 1. I don't know , I've just changed the value from false to true. maybe it didn't compile? 2. More static init of other fields

Comment: File->Invalidate caches.  Restart.  Rebuild.  Try again.

Comment: @Simon, where in Invalidate caches, I can't see it under File.

Comment: Ah, sorry, you're using Eclipse.  Project->Clean.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After a lot of struggles what solved the problem for me is the following:

1. Project -> clean , like Simon suggested.
2. Restart eclipse.
3. Fix build path (after clean , I got error in my build path not refrencing the JRE).
4. Fix android target version. (After clean I got some error on the target).
5. Save files.
6. Restart eclipse (again).

This was one of the strangest things I've encountered as a programmer,
and I'm not really sure until now what the problem was and which of the above steps helped to fix it.

So , I've decided to write all of the steps, hoping it might do some good to some other pour soul.

Simon- Thanks again.